# Magento2 how to get quote order id

Tags: magento2, php, payment-methods, payment

in my authorization request builder as apart of my payment method facade, I need to fetch the quote or order id to pass it to the client....

```php
class AuthorizationRequestBuilder implements BuilderInterface
{
    public function build($buildSubject)
    {
        // get order here (type of order is Magento\Payment\Gateway\Data\Order\OrderAdapter)
        // this order doesn't have an id as its not placed yet
        $order = $buildSubject['payment']->getOrder();
        // how to get the quote id or the reserved order id?
        $quote = null; // <- how to get this?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like this:

```php
    protected $session;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session)
    {
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function build(array $buildSubject)
    {
        $payment = \Magento\Payment\Gateway\Helper\SubjectReader::readPayment($buildSubject);
        $order = $payment->getOrder();
        $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    }
```

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: there is no order id as the order hasn't being placed yet

Comment: I've updated my answer, can you try ?